# SharePoint 2007 Delegate Control and WSDL

Tags: sharepoint-designer, delegate

Is there a way to create custom delegate control in sub-sites without having to restart the IIS server?
I have full admin/SharePoint designer access to the sub-site, just not the IIS installation.

Also Is there a way to obtain the parent site WSDL asmx without having access to the parent SharePoint site, but having full control of the current sub-site?

I never see the option for the Style Library or the _layouts/_vti_bin folders to be created.
Can anyone shed some light on these items and how they can be obtained/copied to the parent folder without having access to the parent folder?

Comment: @TeckniX: Hi and welcome to SharePoint Overflow! I strongly recommend you split this question into two different ones (also it looks like the text is cut off on your 2nd one). Then it's easy for people to find, answer and vote on so you get the best results. You can use the `edit` link to change your question. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with delegate controls is just one of the main developer changes which requires an IISReset or recycling the app pool for the current site unfortunately. This is because SharePoint agressively caches a great deal of "infrequently changing" data for performance.

Sorry, can't help on your other question.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the help - Guess I'm doomed for WSDL

On the Style Library, anyway to obtain that without having access to the parent sharepoint site?

Answer (score 1):

i havent tested this, but as long as your delegate control is placed in partially trusted location (bin) and not global assembly cache (GAC) i cant see why it shouldnt work without an IISRESET. But i would have to test it to be sure. EDIT: ok chris piped in with his answer while i was writing this. He sounds kind of convincing, so he might have a point :-)

The web services can always be reached through the /_VTI_BIN/ virtual directory from any subsite since its a vdir on the virtual web on IIS

Answer (score 0):

I think I have seen scenarios where there is no need to iisreset/recycle app pool with delegate controls.

Perhaps it matters whether it's an assembly based control vs ascx based control or as Anders mentioned, whether it's in the GAC vs the bin.